# What's the way of record traceback info into a file using LOGBOOK

Tags: python, logging

I'm new to Python 3rd party logging module LOGBOOK. After reading the documents provided by the auther, I do not find an equivalence to:

logging.exception

which will easily record the traceback info for me.

Am I missing some information from the docs? And how can I implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[`logging.exception`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.exception) is just a convenience method that calls the `.exception` method of the root `Logger` instance. `logbook` doesn't seem to have such a method on the module itself, so you'll have to initialize a new `Logger` (in this respect, the API is compatible).

```
from logbook import Logger
log = Logger('exceptions')
try:
    raise Exception()
except:
    log.exception()
```